# IronPython: How do I connect to a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, ironpython

I have a DigitalOcean droplet running a MySQL server working perfectly well. I am trying to connect to this server via a IronPython desktop app in Visual Studio.

Here is my code for connecting to the database:

```
import wpf
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')

from System.Data import DataSet
from System.Data.Odbc import OdbcConnection, OdbcDataAdapter

from System.Windows import Application, Window

    class MyWindow(Window):
        def __init__(self):
            wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'Vulpes.xaml')

            connectString = "Server=***.***.***.***;Database=****;Uid=root;Password=****"

            query = "SELECT * FROM users"

            connection = OdbcConnection(connectString)
            adaptor = OdbcDataAdapter(query, connection)
            dataSet = DataSet()

            connection.Open()
            adaptor.Fill(dataSet)
            connection.Close()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

The issue here is with the connection.Open() and connection.Close(functions), if I comment out those parts, everything works great. The username, server address, password, and DB name are all correct and the query is a valid query.

I'm thinking my method is just outdated, and while I'd love to do something more modern, IronPython only supports a very limited amount of Python modules, and so I'm having trouble finding another way to do it this way. There's not even a list of all the supported modules in their documentation, so you just have to look through MySQL modules and do trial-and-error.

If anyone has a better way of connecting to a MySQL DB via IronPython, I would love to hear it.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There is no ; between root and password in the connection string. Also, pls bear in mind that "does not work" is not a particularly informative error description. You should provide the exact error message.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah sorry, I'm not sure why that's there. There is a semicolon in the source code. I fixed the original post to put it in.

As for the exact error message, I get nothing except for "exited with error code 1". I tried to debug it using the VS debugger but I just got the same result.